# switch dentro de otro switch

Tags: c, menú, codeblocks

Mi problema es el siguiente: quiero hacer un submenu dentro del menú en mi programa (no lo había hecho antes). No encuentro mi error. Le agradecería a quien pueda notarlo. Les mando el main del programa. Muchas gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "header.h"
int main()
{
    int option,option2,option3;
    T_empleados reg;
    T_estudiantes reg1;
    do
    {
        printf("Ingrese la operacion que desee realizar:");
        printf("\n 1: Cargar los archivos:");
        printf("\n 2: Mostrar los archivos:");
        printf("\n 3: Actualizar(con un 7.8%) los sueldos de aquellos
               estudaintes que superen un promedio de 7:");
        printf("\n 4: SALIR.\n");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option)
        {
        case 1:
            do
            {
                printf("\n 11: Cargar el archivo 'empleados':");
                printf("\n 12: Cargar el archivo 'estudiantes':");
                printf("\n 13 Volver al menu principal.\n");
                scanf(&option2);
                switch(option2)
                {
                case 11:
                    pfemp=fopen("empleados","wb");
                    if(!pfemp)
                    {
                        printf("No se ha podido abrir el archivo.");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    while(Carga_archivo_empleado(&reg)==1)
                    {
                        fwrite(&reg,sizeof(T_empleados),1,pfemp);
                    }
                    fclose(pfemp);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    pfest=fopen("estudiantes","wb");
                    if(!pfemp)
                    {
                        printf("No se ha podido abrir el archivo.");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    while(Carga_archivo_estudiante(&reg1)==1)
                    {
                        fwrite(&reg1,sizeof(T_estudiantes),1,pfest);
                    }
                    fclose(pfest);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(option2!=13);
            break;
        case 2:
            do
            {
                printf("\n 21: Mostrar el archivo 'empleados':");
                printf("\n 22: Mostrar el archivo 'estudiantes':");
                printf("\n 23 Volver al menu principal.\n");
                scanf(&option3);
                switch(option3)
                {
                case 21:
                    pfemp=fopen("empleados","rb");
                    if(!pfemp)
                    {
                        printf("No se ha podido abrir el archivo.");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    fread(&reg,sizeof(T_empleados),1,pfemp);
                    printf("Apellido\tNombre\tDNI\tSueldo");
                    while(!feof(pfemp))
                    {
                        Mostrar_archivo_empleado(&reg);
                        fread(&reg,sizeof(T_empleados),1,pfemp);
                    }
                    fclose(pfemp);
                    break;
                case 22:
                    pfest=fopen("estudiantes","rb");
                    if(!pfest)
                    {
                        printf("No se ha podido abrir el archivo.");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    fread(&reg1,sizeof(T_estudiantes),1,pfest);
                    printf("Apellido\tNombre\tDNI\tPromedio");
                    while(!feof(pfest))
                    {
                        Mostrar_archivo_estudiante(&reg1);
                        fread(&reg1,sizeof(T_estudiantes),1,pfest);
                    }
                    fclose(pfest);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(option2!=23);
            break;
        case 3:
            Actualizar_archivos(&reg,&reg1);
            break;
        }
    }
    while(option!=4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: te recomiendo que escribas cada menu en funciones diferentes :(, por cierto.. en que momento te da el error? o que haces para poder reproducirlo?

Comment: Perdon. Olvide mencionar eso. No me da error, sino que no deja de pedirme el submenu de ambas opciones del menu (case 1 y 2).

Comment: Lo siento, pero formatee el codigo. Si ingresas la opción (11) después del primer menú, no deja pasar? por que no usas `scanf("%d",&option);` en todas partes? se supone que debes formatear como int :P

Comment: @ArieCwHat muchas gracias... no se porque no veia eso! Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Amén de otros tantos errores y problemas en tu código me centro en el que comentas:

```
    case 2:
        do
        {
            scanf(&option3);
            switch(option3)
            {
              // ...
             }
        }
        while(option2!=23);
        break;
```

`scanf` está actualizando `option3` y, sin embargo, el bucle espera un valor concreto en `option2`.

Por favor, no anides `switchs`... no tengas funciones de más de 20 o 30 líneas. Divide el programa en funciones... tu salud y tus notas te lo agradecerán.

Comment: muchas gracias!lo tendre en cuenta.

Comment: Puedes agregar la solución al problema que está en los comentarios de la pregunta? Para que puedan aceptarla como respuesta correcta y no tener problemas con las buenas practicas de este sitio :P

Comment: Eso me recuerda al kernel de linux ["Si tu función es muy larga, divídela en otras, si te preocupa el rendimiento, puedes indicarle al compilador para que las reemplace inline, y probablemente hará un mejor trabajo de lo que hubiera hecho"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst#6-functions)